# Unity Interface DataSo switch

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tried to get rid of the switch structure using the interface, but I couldn't figure out how to get rid of the switch structure.
The codes are briefly as follows: I get the data CoinDataSo,
I Add Coins according to Dictionary key name with CoinManager,
The objects match the class names and I process the data into the objects according to those names.
I am printing UI Values with the name of the corresponding object using the Multiplication Object.
In RunManager, the Switch Controls Where This UI Writes, How can I make the value in the Switch Control fixed?
codes:
CoinDataSo.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Coin" , menuName = "ScriptableObjects/CoinDataSo" , order = 1)]
public class CoinDataSo : ScriptableObject
{  
  public string prefabName;
  public GameObject prefab;
  public int damage;
}
```

CoinManager.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Windows;

public class CoinManager : MonoBehaviour
{
  
  public List<CoinDataSo> coins=new List<CoinDataSo>();
  Dictionary<string, Coin> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, Coin>();

  public void Start()
  {
    AddDictionary();
  }
  void AddDictionary()
  {
    foreach(CoinDataSo coin in coins)
    {
      keyValuePairs.Add(coin.name , new Coin() { CoinName = coin.name , Damage = coin.damage });
    }
  }
  public Coin GetCoin(string name)
  {
    return keyValuePairs[name];
  }  

}
```

Coin.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Coin 
{
   string coinName;
   int damage;
  public int Damage { get => damage; set => damage = value; }
  public string CoinName { get => coinName; set => coinName = value; }
}
```

Picket

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
GameObject go = other.gameObject;
  if(go != null)
  {
    foreach(CoinDataSo coinDataSo in manager.coins)
    {
      if(go.tag == coinDataSo.name)
      {       
        ICoin iCoin = go.GetComponent<ICoin>();
        if(iCoin != null)
        {
          manager.SkorAdd(iCoin.CoinName , iCoin.Damage);
        }
       
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ICoin.cs

```
public interface ICoin 
{
  string CoinName { get; set; }
  int Damage { get; set; }
  float MoveSpeed { get; set; }    

}
```

Obje

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    [Serializable]
    public class CopperCoin : MonoBehaviour, ICoin
    {  
      string coinName;
      int damage ;
      float speed;
    
      RunManager runManager;
      
      public void Start()
      {
        runManager = FindAnyObjectByType<RunManager>();
        speed = runManager.coinMoveSpeed;
        
        coinName = runManager.GetCoin(this.GetType().Name.ToString()).CoinName;
        damage = runManager.GetCoin(this.GetType().Name.ToString()).Damage;
        this.tag = coinName;
    
      }
    }
```

I want to save the switch here
RunManager.cs

```
 public void SkorAdd(string coinName , int damage)
 {
   switch(coinName)
   {
     case "CopperCoin":
     CopperCoinAdd(damage);
     break;
     case "SilverCoin":
     SilverCoinAdd(damage);
     break;
     case "GoldCoin":
     GoldCoinAdd(damage);
     break;
   }    
 }
```

Comment: To make sure I understood: you want a modular single solution to cover any coin usage (gold, silver or copper) without a switch, so the code auto-magically knows what coint it is and what to add and where, yes? If, so, is there any difference between Copper / Silver / Gold CoinAdd (apart from the func name) and the class usage? If I understood wrong, please re-explain and rephrase :)

Comment: No, there is no, the only difference between them is that the name and value data are different, there will be a process of writing the values to the different UI Part in the switch control, but the switch should not capture it manually, since the name value is unique, it should capture it from there and write the necessary UI values.

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can do is to get all ICoin instances.

```
var array = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<ICoin>();
```

then you can find ICoin instance using CoinName.

```
var selectedICoin = array.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.CoinName==coinName);
```

and then call Add method from ICoin (you will need to make abstract/virtual Add method in ICoin interface).

```
selectedICoin.Add(damage);
```

Comment: If I understand me correctly you want me to create Copper Coin Add object in .cs file.
If you say so, I don't want this. I will enter uiManager from Admin and print the text, that is, the text with the name of CopperCoin or another coin.
I add the damages and their names by removing them from the data.
I want the Damage data of the coin it hit during impact, but I want it to capture it without a switch.

Comment: can you specify what is difference between
CopperCoinAdd(damage);
 SilverCoinAdd(damage);
 GoldCoinAdd(damage);

Comment: also can you show what CopperCoinAdd,SilverCoinAdd & GoldCoinAdd looks like?

Comment: codes same differences damage,

Comment: public void SkorAdd(CopperCoin g, int damage)
  {
    CopperCoinAdd(damage);
  }
Can I Capture This Way?

Comment: is it okay if you write CopperCoinAdd(int damage) function inside CopperCoin class? if so then you can use interface methods for that.

Comment: There is no problem, but instead of using it this way, I want it to be captured there in the manager.